# Getting Connection refused message with GoDaddy Domain and AWS Static web hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, connection-refused

I want to use GoDaddy Domain (for example:- mydomain.com )

Steps which I followed In AWS Console:

```
**Step [2] :-** Create Key Pair in AWS
**Step [3] :-** Created hosted Zone  by default it was having 2 Record Set.         
**Step [4] :-** In S3 I followed below mentioned steps
        (i) Created a bucket  with bucketName mydomain.com
        (ii) Enabled Static website hosting.
        (iii)  Provided Index file index.html 
        (iv) Permissions :
                **Block Public Access** -OFF
                **Bucket Policy-**

{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Statement": [
 {
 "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal": {
 "AWS": "*"
 },
 "Action": "s3:GetObject",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydomain.com/*"
 }
 ]
}

   **Step [5]:** Created a FreeTier Instance for Ubuntu Platform:
           **IP4 Public Access:** 13.XXX.XX.XXX
           **Public DNS IP4:** ec2-13-XXX-XX-XXX.XX-XXXXX-1.XXXXXX.amazonaws.com  

**Step [6] :** in Route 53 create a new RecordSet of type A with below mentioned
```

details:
            **Name:** mydomain.com
            **Type:** A
            **Value:** 13.XXX.XX.XXX       ( IP4 Public Access Value from Step 5)
   **Step [7] :** In Route 53 edited NS Type RecordSset value, added Public DNS IP4 value
                Now NS Value look like:-

```
        ns-XXXXXXX.com.
        ns-XXXXXXX.net.
        ns-XXXXXXX.org.
        ns-XXXXXXX.uk.
        ec2-13-XXX-XX-XXX.XX-XXXXX-1.XXXXXX.amazonaws.com  

  **Step [8]:**  Open port 80 in Security Group
```

**Final change in GoDaddy.com:**

**Step [9] :** chnged nameservers from default to custom and added below mention 4 name servers:

```
        ns-XXXXXXX.com.
        ns-XXXXXXX.net.
        ns-XXXXXXX.org.
        ns-XXXXXXX.uk.
```

When i am trying to hit mydomain.com getting :
“This site can’t be reached
mydomain.com refused to connect.”

Answer (score 0):

Finally my issue is resolved.
In Route 53, I added **"A"** type **Record Set** and now I am able to access mydomain.com 
*Here I learned one  thing that For static web hosting ec2 Instance is not required*